# How To echo constant Variable in php with variable name

Tags: php, constants

I started learning php and Recently I've faced a problem with a constant variable in my code. recently I've created the Ninja class in the editor and set a stealth constant to the string "MAXIMUM", then I try to echo it to the page using the scope resolution operator (::).

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title> Scope it Out! </title>
 </head>

<body>

<p>
  <?php
  class Person {

  }
  class Ninja extends Person {
    // Add your code here...
    const stealth = "Maximum";
  }
  // ...and here!
  if(Ninja::stealth){

    echo stealth;
    }

  ?>

  </p>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Now question is "How can echo the **const Variable** in php???"

Comment: `echo Ninja::stealth`. FYI, it is common practice to name constants in all capital letters.

Comment: The same way you access it in the `if` test: `echo Ninja::stealth`

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ - not really a duplicate of that: `stealth` is a constant, not a variable

Comment: `echo stealth;` is expecting a constant in the global scope, not one that belongs to the class.

Comment: Not really answered, because i already check it out

Comment: OP is also trying to print the value of the constant, not its name.

Comment: @Flosculus i tried it but it don't work?

Comment: I am getting this error in this code Use of undefined constant stealth - assumed 'stealth' (line 18)stealth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already accessed it by `echo Ninja::stealth;`
**Try this:**
Live Demo : https://eval.in/88040

```
 class Person {

      }
      class Ninja extends Person {
        // Add your code here...
        const stealth = "Maximum";
      }
      // ...and here!
      if(Ninja::stealth){
        echo Ninja::stealth;
       }
```

Output:

```
Maximum
```

Answer (score 1):

Or something like this:

```
<?php
  class Person {

  }
  class Ninja extends Person {
    // Add your code here...
    const stealth = "Maximum";
    public function getCamo()
    {
        return self::stealth;
    }
  }

  $ningen = new Ninja;
  echo $ningen->getCamo();

?>
```